# git show not working with python check_output

Tags: python, git, subprocess, git-show

I am writing a python script in which I have to read the output of the `git show` command from the script. I decided to use python's `subprocess.check_output` function.

But its giving me `No such file or directory` error.

*Running from python*:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(['pwd'])
'/Users/aapa/Projects/supertext\n'
>>> subprocess.check_output(['git show', 'c9a89aa:supertext/src/com/stxt/supercenter/rest/api/bootstrap/BootstrapDTO.java'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>>>
```

*Running directly*:

```
$ pwd
/Users/aapa/Projects/supertext
$ git show c9a89aa:supertext/src/com/stxt/supercenter/rest/api/bootstrap/BootstrapDTO.java
package com.stxt.supercenter.rest.api.bootstrap;

import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
import com.stxt.base.rolepermission.enums.Role;
import com.stxt.superbase.profile.agent.bean.Agent;
import com.stxt.supercenter.rest.api.profile.agnet.AgentDTO;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
.
.
.
```

One thing to point out `git show` outputs in `vi` style i.e. not the complete file is getting printed directly but the part of file is printed to cover the complete scree with a `:` in the end to print next line or to quit.

Why I am getting error using `check_output`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
subprocess.check_output(['git', 'show', 'c9a89aa:supertext/src/com/stxt/supercenter/rest/api/bootstrap/BootstrapDTO.java'])
```

Otherwise, your code tries to execute a command literally containing a space ("`git show`") instead of the command `git` with `show` as its first argument.